# get shingle result from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm already familiar with `shingle` analyzer and I am able to create a shingle analyzer as follows:

```
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 10,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "shingle_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase"
            "filter_shingle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "filter_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "max_shingle_size": 2,
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "output_unigrams": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and then I use the defined analyzer in `mapping` for a field in my document named `content`.The problem is the `content` field is a very long text and I want to use it as data for a autocomplete suggester, so I just need one or two words that follow the matched phrase. I wonder if there is a way to get the `search` (or `suggest` or `analyze`) API result as shingles too. By using `shingle analyzer` the `elastic` itself indexes the text as shingles, is there a way to access those shingles?

For instance,
the query I pass is :

```
GET the_index/_search
{
  "_source": ["content"],
  "explain": true, 

      "query" : {
        "match" : { "content.shngled_field": "news" }
      }
}
```

the result is :

```
    {
  "took" : 395,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 7.8647532,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_shard" : "[v3_kavan_telegram_201911][0]",
        "_node" : "L6vHYla-TN6CHo2I6g4M_A",
        "_index" : "v3_kavan_telegram_201911",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "g1music/70733",
        "_score" : 7.8647532,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "Find the latest breaking news and information on the top stories, weather, business, entertainment, politics, and more."
....
}
```

as you can see the result contains the whole `content` filed which is a very long text. The result I expect is

```
"content" : "news and information on"
```

which is the matched shingle itself.

Answer (score 0):

After you've created an index & ingested a doc

```json
PUT sh
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "shingled": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "shingle_analyzer": {
          "type": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "filter_shingle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "filter_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "max_shingle_size": 2,
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "output_unigrams": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST sh/_doc/1
{
  "content": "and then I use the defined analyzer in mapping for a field in my document named content.The problem is the content field is a very long text and I want to use it as data for a autocomplete suggester, so I just need one or two words that follow the matched phrase. I wonder if there is a way to get the search (or suggest or analyze) API result as shingles too. By using shingle analyzer the elastic itself indexes the text as shingles, is there a way to access those shingles?"
}
```

You can call either `_analyze` w/ the corresponding analyzer to see how a given text would be tokenized:

```json
GET sh/_analyze
{
  "text": "and then I use the defined analyzer in mapping for a field in my document named content.The problem is the content field is a very long text and I want to use it as data for a autocomplete suggester, so I just need one or two words that follow the matched phrase. I wonder if there is a way to get the search (or suggest or analyze) API result as shingles too. By using shingle analyzer the elastic itself indexes the text as shingles, is there a way to access those shingles?",
  "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer"
}
```

Or check out the [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-termvectors.html) information:

```json
GET sh/_termvectors/1
{
  "fields" : ["content.shingled"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "payloads" : true,
  "positions" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

Will you be [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting) too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is you can't use the _analyze to search data. I want to search in data and then as result get the matched shingle. @joe

Comment: you can use `"explain":true` at the top level of your query.

Comment: just did what you said. A JSON object is added to result that there is no shingle in it :/ @joe

Comment: Can you update your question with what exactly you expect the response to be?

Comment: For newer versions of ES, I think the term vectors API syntax has been updated: GET /my-index-000001/_termvectors/1 [(see docs)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-termvectors.html)